# Different authentication mechanisms on the same port (TLS for grpc and Authorization for REST)

Tags: go, ssl, grpc

I am trying to run a server that can accept both grpc requests with mutual TLS authentication (`tls.RequireAndVerifyClientCert`) and a standard HTTP Web Server that authenticates requests based on the `Authorization` header.

I feel that it is better to leave the TLS verification to the standard library so I would prefer to enforce `tls.RequireAndVerifyClientCert` for grpc. However for a Web App, browsers are not going to forward a client certificate.

I have been trying to use something like [this](https://github.com/philips/grpc-gateway-example/blob/master/cmd/serve.go) with a handler to serves the requests differently based on the request. Unfortunately, the peer certificate is not forwarded to the grpc handler, only the tls config from the Web App is taken into account (can't do both).

Ideally, I also would like to keep all in 1 binary (no reverse proxy).

Do you see a solution or would you compromise and verify the authentication manually?

Comment: Obviously you can't use RequireAndVerifyClientCert if a certificate isn't always required. The client certificate should be available in [Peer.AuthInfo](https://godoc.org/google.golang.org/grpc/peer), though (specifically `Peer.AuthInfo.(credentials.TLSInfo).State.VerifiedChains`).

Comment: I think I will go with `tls.VerifyClientCertIfGiven` and just refuse the connection if I get into a grpc handler with `len(tlsInfo.State.VerifiedChains) == 0`, what do you think?

Comment: Seems like that should work, yes.